# Probability of getting a 'Tier 1' hero out of 78 heroes given a choice between either 2 or 4 heroes

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose there are 78 heroes. Only one of them is considered to be 'Tier 1'. At the beginning of some game you are given a choice between either 2 heroes or 4 heroes. The question is: how advantegeous is it to choose out of 4 heroes to choosing out of 2, if by advantageous we mean to have a higher probability of getting a 'Tier 1' hero?
My logic is to first compute the total number of 2-hero combinations and 4-hero combinations:
$$C^2_{78}=\frac{78!}{(78-2)!2!}=3003;  C^4_{78}=\frac{78!}{(78-4)!4!}=1426425$$
The prbability of getting a 'Tier 1' hero if we choose between 2 is $\frac{77}{3033}\approx0.0256$, while the probability of getting a 'Tier 1' hero if we choose between 4 is $\frac{77\cdot76\cdot75}{1426425}\approx0.3077$.
So, the advantage seems to be $\frac{77\cdot76\cdot75}{1426425}\cdot\frac{3033}{77}=12$. So, you are 12 times more likely to get a 'Tier 1' hero if you choose out of 4 heroes than out of 2. Is this logic correct? The advantage seems to be too big

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you have two groups "Tier 1" and non-"Tier 1". And you choose 2 or 4 heroes without replacement. This is a typical case of using the hypergeometric distribution. The probability to choose 1 Tier, given two heroes are drawn is

$$P(X=1|h=2)=\frac{\binom{1}{1}\cdot \binom{77}{1}  }{\binom{78}{2} }$$

Equvalently, the probability to choose 1 Tier, given 4 heroes are drawn is

$$P(X=1|h=4)=\frac{\binom{1}{1}\cdot \binom{77}{3}  }{\binom{78}{4} }$$

I leave it to you to calculate the probabilities and interpret them.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are only concerned with the advantage in getting a Tier 1 hero,

we can simply take the ratio $\dfrac{4}{78}/\dfrac{2}{78} = 2:1$

The full calculations below are actually unnecessary

P(Tier 1 from 2) $= \Large\dfrac{\binom11\binom{77}1}{\binom{78}2} =\frac1{39}$

P(Tier 1 from 1) $= \Large\dfrac{\binom11\binom{77}3}{\binom{78}4} =\frac2{39}$

Advantage ratio $= 2:1$ for choosing from $4$